# timing belt 96 honda accord vtec

Tags: honda, timing-belt, motors, camshaft, vtec

So the other day I was driving and my timing belt broke I tried to turn the key a few times then tore off the valve cover and noticed that the timing belt was broken people have told me the engine might be junk now how do I check

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check is to fit a new timing belt, turn the engine over by hand and make sure it feels free and isn't making any odd noises.  Then do a compression test and see if it's still got compression.

If that all checks out then you should be okay to try and start it.  If not, the only option to you is to pop the cylinder head off and take a look (unless you have access to a bore scope to look inside the engine).

Answer (score 0):

Check the valve adjustment on all the valves. If they are at or near specification then the engine will be Ok. If it is a four cylinder engine chances are good that it will not have bent any of the valves and will therefore run normally after a new timing belt is installed.